# Does Java 6 support legacy JAXB1 out of the box?

Tags: java, jaxb

does Java 6 support legacy JAXB1 out of the box? According to JAXB guide, I can use JAXB1 with JAXB2 libraries, just add jaxb1-impl.jar to classpath. But it seems that this works only when using JAXB RI as standalone package. It doesn't work for me with Java 6 classes out of the box.

Thanks, Jan

Comment: why do you have to use jaxb1?

Comment: It may depend on your version of Java 6.  Java 6 JAXB support changed as of update 10.

Comment: I need jabx1 because of legacy classes I cannot change

Comment: I can update Java 6 to the latest version if need be. What changes are you talking about?

Comment: Which implementation of JAXB 1.0 are you using:  Metro (the RI), TopLink JAXB, XDK JAXB, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Jaxb is backword compataible. You can use generate binding classes using jaxb1 , compile it into a seperate jar.

Deploy the above compiled code in jvm6. There will be no change needed in the client code. Jaxb2 will automatically pickup the legacy binary.
--Kiran.Kumar